# Angular transfer observable using routes

Tags: angular, routes

i try to send an object to a new component. To do this i created this method:

```
 getRecord(blogId: Observable<Note>) {

this.router.navigate(['/blogdetail'], { queryParams: { Id: blogId}});
```

}

This method is called whenever the user clicks on a button.

In my Url i can see that, this component sends the object but the other component is always showing Error 404

Here is my Code for this component:

```
interface Note{
imageUrl: string;
title: string;
body: string;

}

 ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.note = params['Id'];
  const blogtitle = this.note['title'];
  const blogbody =this.note['body'];
  const image =this.note['imageUrl'];
this.imageUrl = image;
  this.title = blogtitle;
  this.body = blogbody;

});
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

}

Comment: Things to include in order for more help: your routing configuration, the url that you are trying to hit, the value of blogId prior to routing.